# Retain which fragment is active in the BottomNavigationView with navigationComponent

Tags: java, android, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, bottomnavigationview

I set up my navigation system with fragment thanks to the Navigation Architecture. However, there is a button in my Home fragment that allows me to navigate to another fragment, but when I click on the Settings menu of my Navigation View for instance and after on the Home one, the fragment displayed is the basic one, not the one I had launched previously.

Example:

[image]

I would like to know how to show the players fragment in this case.

---

My code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications).build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }
}
```

Navigation graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="fr.frenchapplab.testbottomnav.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_playersFragment"
            app:destination="@id/playersFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="fr.frenchapplab.testbottomnav.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="fr.frenchapplab.testbottomnav.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/playersFragment"
        android:name="fr.frenchapplab.testbottomnav.PlayersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_players"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_players" />
</navigation>
```

And I use this code to launch the players fragment:

```
Button mybutton = root.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
mybutton.setOnClickListener(view1 -> Navigation.findNavController(view1).navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_playersFragment));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the navController's addOnDestinationChangedListener() method to manually keep track of which fragment is being shown, and then create some if conditions to navigate to other places if necessary. It's not all that elegant but something like this should work if tweaked correctly:

```
//declare lateinit var homeFragmentDestingation
 
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(object : NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
            override fun onDestinationChanged(controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination, arguments: Bundle?) {
                
                //keep track of destinations
                previousDestination = currentDestination
                currentDestination = destination

               if (destination.label == "Home" && homeFragmentDestingation?.label == "FILL THIS IN" && maybe other conditions here) {
                    navigateToFragment()
                } else if (tweak this as necessary) {
                    homeFragmentDestingation = destination
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "destination is ${homeFragmentDestingation?.label} \n previous destination is ${previousDestination?.label}")
            }
        })
```

Comment: It's a good idea but that could create some issues with arguments..